# Add lines between the rows of a rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, datatable, richfaces, richdatatable

How can I add lines between the rows of a dataTable in JSF - so the table looks something like a matrix ?

Below is my view file :

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{myController.myModel}" var="myManager" id="managerTable" >
```

A quick search pointed that adding rules="rows" in the dataTable would work. I tried but with no result. Apparently, when I add rules="rows" for a h:dataTable, there are lines that are introduced between the rows.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.myModel}" rules="rows" var="myManager" id="managerTable" >
```

But it fails the moment I change to rich:dataTable.

How can I obtain the same result in rich:dataTable too?

I use JSF 2.0 and richfaces 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<rich:dataTable>` has `rowClass` attribute, if you want lines between rows you can make a CSS class like this one:

```
.row-line {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

EDIT:
The first row in a dataTable has the `rf-dt-fst-r` class. So in case you'd want to add a line above the table:

```
.row-line.rf-dt-fst-r {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: And what about the first row?

Comment: And how to assign a special class to the first row from within a `<rich:dataTable>` tag :) ?

Comment: @skuntsel That you can't do. Do you need to? I mean there is no difference between `.row.first-row` and `.custom-first-row`, is there?

Comment: @Makhiel I see that this solution is not working in IE. I see the lines perfectly in chrome, but in IE there is not even a hint of them. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: Not even IE should have problems with this. Are you sure the style is not getting overwritten? (I tried it in IE8 and it works fine)